Spectrum of a positive definite differential operator
When solving the two body problem in three dimensions in my QM lectures, you end up, essentially, with the Legendre associated equation. In terms of the angular momentum operator:
$$L^2Y_l^m(\theta, \varphi)=\lambda \hbar^2Y_l^m(\theta, \varphi)$$
More explicitly:
$$\left(\frac{1}{sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right)+\frac{1}{sin^2\theta}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \varphi^2}\right)Y_l^m(\theta,\varphi)=-\lambda Y_l^m(\theta,\varphi)$$
Now, just by looking at this equation, my professor claims the operator is positive definite, and therefore all of its eigenvalues will be equal or greater than zero ($\lambda_i\geq 0$). Nonetheless, I don't know why he can state this. In the one dimensional case, I know a Sturm-Liouville operator's spectrum is $\lambda_i\geq 0$ if said operator is regular, symmetric and its (separate) boundary conditions are such that:
$$\alpha y(a)+\tilde{\alpha}y'(a)=0$$
$$\beta y(b)+\tilde{\beta}y'(b)=0$$
Where $\alpha \tilde{\alpha}\leq 0$ and $\beta\tilde{\beta}\geq 0$. Nonetheless, my professor made this claim just by looking at the equation. My best guess is we are implicitly imposing some boundary conditions, but the only ones I can think of is the evident one: $Y_l^m(\theta,0)=Y_l^m(\theta, 2\pi)$; $Y_l^m(\theta,0)'=Y_l^m(\theta, 2\pi)'$. Is my professor's claim correct? After all, we do indeed get a positive spectrum, but I don't know whether his explanation is correct, and it certainly does not sound rigorous.

What is the explicit expression for $L^2$?

$$L^2= L_x^2+L_y^2+L_z^2$$ is the sum of three squares of the self adjoint operators $$L_{nm} = -i \ (x_n \ \partial_{x_m} - x_m \ \partial_{x_n})$$ by
$$\int f(x)^* \ \left(i \ (x_n \ \partial_{x_m} - x_m \ \partial_{x_n})\right)^2 \ f(x) \ d^3x=
\int \left|i \ (x_n \ \partial_{x_m} - x_m \ \partial_{x_n}) f(x) \right|^2 \  d^3x >0$$
by partial integration on all functions with vanishing surface integrals at $\infty$.
In spherical coordinates, the positivity demonstration includes the area element on the unit sphere with a factor $\sin \theta \ d\theta$, where the $\sin \theta$ is the metric scale factor of $ r  \sin \theta d\phi$ along the paralell circles.
By partial integration twice on the space of functions with value zero and/or derivative at the poles
$$\int  f^*(\theta)  \  \left( -\frac{1}{\sin \theta} \partial_\theta\left(\sin \theta \partial_\theta g(\theta)\right) \right) \  \sin \theta \ d\theta 
= -\int  f^*(\theta)  \  \left(  \partial_\theta\left(\sin \theta \partial_\theta g(\theta)\right) \right) \   \ d\theta= 
\int  g(\theta)  \  \left( -\frac{1}{\sin \theta} \partial_\theta\left(\sin \theta \partial_\theta f(\theta)\right) \right)^* \  \sin \theta \ d\theta $$
the operator is symmetric and together with $$L_z^2 = -\partial_\phi^2$$ one can show that the Laplacian $-\Delta_{S^2}=L^2$  or $\mathbb R^3$ restricted to unit sphere is a selfadjoint, positive operator.
